# Getting data from a NSURLConnection POST method

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios9, nsurlconnection

I have subclassed an `NSData` object into my .h and .m files like so:

```
@interface Test : NSData // and so forth
```

I have created a function that generates `JSON` data to send back to the server as a `POST`. I get to this part in the code:

```
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Question 1:

How do I tell when the connection/post is done? Is it in the if/else below?

```
if(conn) {
    NSLog(@"Connection Successful");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Connection could not be made");
}
```

Question 2:

How do I use these delegate methods below to get the data that is returned?

```
// This method is used to receive the data which we get using post method.
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data

// This method receives the error report in case of connection is not made to server. 
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error 

// This method is used to process the data after connection has made successfully.
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
```

Comment: BTW, if you use `NSURLSession`, you can enjoy the simplicity of block-based completion handler (sort of like `NSURLConnection`'s `sendAsynchronousRequest` ... no delegate methods to worry about if you don't want to), but (a) it's cancelable; and (b) you avoid using the now deprecated `NSURLConnection`.

Comment: Also, I'm unclear why you'd bother subclassing `NSData`. That's generally unnecessary. Typically you'd just use `NSMutableData`.

Comment: @Rob thanks. Yes I will use NSURLSession. Should have checked if it was deprecated first.

Answer (score 2):

this worked for me

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"API link"]

NSLog(@"%@",url.standardizedURL);
NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                                           NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
 {
     NSLog(@"balh %@",connectionError);
     if (data.length > 0 && connectionError == nil)
     {
         NSDictionary *response = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                  options:0
                                                                    error:NULL];
         NSString * string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy];
         NSLog(@"%@ %@",response,string);



         [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

         }];
     }
 }];
```

for checking connection you can use this statements after NSURLConnection statement

```
 if(response){NSLog(@"Connection Established");}else{NSLog(@"Connection not established");}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use delegate methods for verification of operation success and to get the data in returned.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response 
{
    NSLog("@Resp received");
    return;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
    didReceiveData:(NSData *)data 
{
    NSLog("@Data received");
    return
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
  didFailWithError:(NSError *)error 
{
    NSLog("@ERROR: Achtung !: %@",[error localizedDescription]);
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH , 0),, ^{
        NSLog(@"FinishedLoading: In bg thread, do something with data here");

        dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"FinishedLoading: In Main thread, access the UI here");
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Do I return the data from didRecieveData like [_theData appendData]; and then use _theData in my if (conn) loop?

Comment: @cdub - Yes, `didReceiveData` should append to the `NSMutableData`, but you process it in `connectionDidFinishLoading`, not back where you instantiated the `NSURLConnection`.

Answer (score 0):

set HTTP method (POST or GET). Write this lines as it is in your code.

```
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
```